# What does "When's" mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Someone help me understand this sentence: **"When's** the last time you took a holiday?" "When's" means what? "When is", "when was" or "when has"?

Comment: In the context you quote "when was" would be most fitting, since "last time" is in the past.  For "When's the next club meeting", "when is" is a better fit.  It might occasionally be used for "when has", but that is less idiomatic.

Comment: The three auxiliaries that end in /z/ -- _has, is, was_ -- can all be contracted to just the /z/ at the end of the subject NP. This is normal in ordinary speech, and just about obligatory for subject pronouns, so _he's_ can mean _he was, he is,_ or _he has_; the form of the verb that follows will determine which one. And, yes, _when_ **is** the subject of that question, even if somebody said it can't be.

Comment: There is a recent increase in the illogical "When is the last time ...?" usage, perhaps because a more formal version of "When's the last time ...?" is wanted and ""When was the last time ...?" is harder to enunciate. However, it's still relatively uncommon, so the best guess is "When was ...?"

Comment: @JohnLawler: I'm not convinced it can be _was_. I interpret it in that question as _is_, (as Edwin suggests); and with almost all nominal subjects apart from the pronoun _I_, it would be indistinguishable from _is_ whenever there was no explicit time reference. It seems to me that when _was_ in intended, there is always a slight rounding that is audible.

Comment: You may be right. I probly should omit _was_ from the list.